# String or binary data would be truncated.\r\nThe statement has been terminated. while xml insertion

Tags: sql-server, xml

Can you please let me know how do I resolve this problem while inserting xml data into Sql Server 2008

`ex = {"String or binary data would be truncated.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}`

I already replaced `'`, `""` with an empty string

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 26):

Please check the datetype of the column. Make sure it has enough space.

Comment: How to know which column is causing the problem

Answer (score 20):

Check the Database Column Size  and Data length.
 you  will get this error when you are storing data of length greater than that of defined size.

```
    Ex. string Data = "saving this data causes error.";
    int datalength = Data.Length;  // will be 30 characters , greater than defined size

    Customer.Name = Data;
    //you will get error for this line if you have Name (varchar 25, null) in db      .
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a subquery change the `=` between the sub query and main query to `in`.

It may be that you have more than one field for each record of the main query.